# copy asp control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to copy data that is displayed in a asp listview.(I want to email it)

I can grab the information using javascript to grab the html but it is unstyled.

I don't want to have to go inside each control to save the data before each time it is outputted.  Is their a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has been answered, but I thought I would add this too in case it helps. I use the following to return the HTML of a given control. As mentioned, you would just need to include any CSS in the HTML of the Email.

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;

public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Stolen from several blog sites [like this one](http://atominnovation.blogspot.com/2010/06/aspnet-render-control-into-html-string.html).

Answer (score 1):

Html is html, if you keep your formatting in a css you will need to attach related css-classes and tags in the e-mails as well which should be quite simple.

Comment: I guess I will populate the text to a hidden field with the style and have asp send the hidden field via email...